# How does the compiler initialize local arrays with a default value of zero on the stack?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, stack-memory

Let's imagine I define a local array of `int`s with a default value of 0 in my function:

```
void test() {
    int array[256] = {0};
}
```

My understanding of this is that:

the array will be stored in the stack, by pushing 256 zeroes to the stack and consequently increasing the stack pointer. If there was no default value for the array, increasing the stack pointer would have been enough.

Now this is the assembly code produced by the previous snippet:

```
test:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $1024, %esp
    .cfi_offset 7, -12
    .cfi_offset 3, -16
    leal    -1032(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $256, %edx
    movl    %ebx, %edi
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    rep stosl
    addl    $1024, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    .cfi_restore 3
    popl    %edi
    .cfi_restore 7
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   test, .-test
```

I realize this may be a silly question and I am aware that each compiler may act differently, but I'm wondering where the allocation of the array with 256 zeros is happening. Were my assumptions correct or this is happening differently?

(I've not been writing assembly for quite a long time and I'm having some difficulties understanding what's going on)

Comment: Maybe `movl $0, %eax`?

Comment: Examine the code starting with `subl    $1024, %esp` and ending with `addl    $1024, %esp`. Go through each instruction, noting what it does, including its effect on registers and memory. Draw diagrams, etc. Best of luck.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I tend to take the question in the largest font as the most relevant question.

Comment: You are right @MichaelPetch, that produces a different code because it doesn't fill the whole array with the same default value. I thought `{1}` would have copied all ones in the array, but actually it copies 1 in the first element and uses zero for all the remaining elements. This means my question also should be updated actually. I had a wrong assumption.  Anyway adding back that the default value is zero in the title should clear the ambiguities. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The allocation is happening here:

```
    subl    $1024, %esp
```

It is a `sub` on the stack pointer `esp`, because a stack grows *down*.

The array is cleared here:

```
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $256, %edx     
    movl    %ebx, %edi 
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    rep stosl
```

What this does is:

- `rep` : repeat the string operation `ecx` times
- `stosl`: store `eax` in the memory pointed to by `edi` and add 4 to edi, or subtract 4, depending on the direction flag. If it's clear (`cld`), `edi` gets incremented, and decremented otherwise.
  Note that `ebx` is set to point to the start of the array a bit earlier in the code.

And finally, here the array is released:

```
    addl    $1024, %esp
```

---

These are the highlights, but there are a few more instructions of note, so here's the complete listing of the (non-optimized) code:

```
pushl   %ebp                # preserve caller's ebp (decrements esp by 4)
movl    %esp, %ebp          # copy stack pointer to ebp
pushl   %edi                # preserve for caller
pushl   %ebx                # preserve for caller
subl    $1024, %esp         # allocate 1kb on the stack
leal    -1032(%ebp), %ebx   # esp + 1024 + 4 + 4 = ebp; equivalent to mov %esp, %ebx
movl    $0, %eax            # the {0}
movl    $256, %edx          # the repeat count - could have been stored in ecx directly
movl    %ebx, %edi          # init edi to the start of the array
movl    %edx, %ecx          # put 256 in ecx
rep stosl                   # repeat 'mov %eax, %(edi); add $4, %edi' ecx times
addl    $1024, %esp         # release the array
popl    %ebx                # and the preserved registers
popl    %edi
popl    %ebp                
ret
```

Comment: Looks like the operative command here is `rep stosl`, which actually does the zeroing.

Comment: Did you mean "`stosl` : store `eax` into the memory location pointed to by `edi`..."?

Comment: Also - does a segment register come into play here? (I'm rather rusty on my x86 protected mode 64-bit assembler concepts - sorry... :-)

Comment: Yes - `esp` uses `ss`, and `stos` uses `es:edi` (and `movs` uses `ds:esi -> es:edi`. But these days, `ds`, `es` and `ss` are usually the same.

Comment: What's mildly scary is that I could pretty quickly pick out what was going on - and I haven't looked at x86 assembler in at least 20 years. Still, at my age, it's nice to remember anything... :-)

Comment: As @chqrlie points out direction flag as to be set properly, however most calling conventions default the direction flag to being clear (CLD) for forward movement. The general rule is that if you write a function that does _STD_  to reverse the direction, that it should be set back to clear (with _CLD_) before your function returns. In this case of course you want forward movement so the default of forward movement is already correct.

Comment: Thank you @Kenney, very clear! I never met the `rep` opcode before.. I was expecting to find some jump to loop over the array.. :-)

Comment: To add to Michael's point: the `D`irection flag must be clear when calling any other functions, as well as before returning.  The Linux 32 and 64bit ABIs require that it's cleared on function entry and return.  AFAIK, so do the common Windows ABIs.  Also, if you're looking for `stosl` in the Intel manual, you'll find it under `stosd` (DWORD).